# Reset rotation of element back to original state (rotatable.js + jquery UI)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, rotation

I'm trying to make a selected element reset it's rotation from rotatable.js after a certain amount of time if it's been rotated.

Here is an example demo.

http://jsfiddle.net/mnahbfk0/

`$(".draggable").rotatable  ({

  handle: true,
  snap: true,
  snapStep: 22.5,

    });`

What it does right now:
- you can drag the blue element out of the box and rotate it along the center from the red box handle
- The element will reset it's drag back to the box after it's been moved after a certain time.

What I want to happen:
-I'd like to do the same for the rotation. Not sure if its implementable in rotatable.js or how to reset.
- also issue is that once it's rotated, the drag reset seems to be off if it had been rotated and doesn't go back to the center in the dotted square.

Thanks!

https://www.jqueryscript.net/other/CSS3-Rotatable-jQuery-UI.html

Comment: Your Fiddle is not setup properly. You cannot call an HTTP library from within a fiddle. I found a CDN and added the library again, but it has problems. Encountering a `handle.draggable` error.

Comment: @twisty thanks for taking a look. What seems to be the issue? Running fine from my end, it's call all the JS from a CDN or external site, no? At least it's functioning as above. Let me know I can fix it, if so.

Comment: The CDN I Found I think is an earlier version by one of the people that worked on it. I found the Git and no CDN is listed. It also has not been worked on in 2 years. I do not see a HTTPS version of the same JS file linked to, so it will not work in the fiddle.

Comment: @twisty, I'm currently hosting it on my own site, shouldn't that be fine for the time being? It's pulling the js file just fine in the fiddle for me. Rotate function works, just wondering if I can make it reset to original position through the rotatable.js function or by general JS function. I've hosted the latest version on my server (included in header in jfiddle). Sorry if I don't understand what you're trying to convey. Shouldn't I just be able to use some script to reset the rotation after a certain time? thanks!

Comment: No it's not working for me: `TypeError: $(...).rotatable is not a function show:72:19` The Fiddle is unable to load the HTTP linked JS file.

Answer (score 0):

In regards to reverting the rotation, you simply need to set the `angle` option back to `0`, based on the documentation. Try changing the angle in the Revert callback.

```
$(".draggable").rotatable  ({  
  handle: true,
  snap: true,
  snapStep: 22.5,     
}).draggable({
  revert: function () {
    $(this).delay(2500);
    $(this).rotatable("option", "angle", 0);
    return true
  },    
  revertDuration: '400',
  snapTolerance: '0',
  snap: 'true',
  grid: [ 20, 20],
});
```

Otherwise you might consider another library that does what you want. https://github.com/godswearhats/jquery-ui-rotatable